# anchor link posts content at the bottom of current webpage

Tags: javascript, html, css, hyperlink, anchor

My website is a sample of a store selling phones. My issue is, when I click the link to nokia, the body of that html document gets put below the current page as if it's appending. On a side note i also have a header saying "loading..." I can not find that in my index file.

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Cell City's Home Page</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="cs/stylesheet.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>    
  </head>
  <body>
    <div data-role="page" id="home">
    <div class="heading">
      <p class="header1">Cell City
      <small class="header1_small">Where selling cell's is our specialty!</small></p>

      <div class="admin_login">
        <form action="#">
          <p class="header1_login">Login as an Admin</p><br>
          <input class="textboxes" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username">
          <input class="textboxes" type="text" name="password" placeholder="Password">
          <button class="buttons">Log In</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>

      <div class="navbar">
        <a class="nav_link" href="#">Products</a>
        <a class="nav_link" href="#">About Us</a>
      </div>

      <p class="header2">Products</p><br>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="product">
          <a href="nokia.html">Nokia</a>
          <image src="images/nokia.jpg" alt="PICTURE!" height="200" width="200"/>
        </div>
        <div class="product">
          <a href="motorola.html">Motorola</a>
          <image src="images/motorola.jpg" alt="PICTURE!" height="200" width="200"/>
        </div>
        <div class="product">
          <a href="iphone.html">Iphone</a>
          <image src="images/iphone.jpg" alt="PICTURE!" height="200" width="200"/>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: post script.js code

Comment: Can you provide us the Js code? Also, i don't understand very well what are you asking for, but if you want to put some HTML at some place before/after some other elements, you can check `Element.insertAdjacentHTML`.